# Print Command is not working when extract text from PDF file in Python

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have used this code to extract all the text from PDF file in Python, But When I use print command in last then no output is coming, Please suggest.

```
import PyPDF2

pip install PyPDF2

PDFObject=open('C:/Users/jay.jaiswal/Desktop/Training/bullying.pdf','rb')

PDFReader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(PDFObject)

print(PDFReader.numPages)

pageObj=PDFReader.getPage(0)

print(pageObj.extractText())
```

Comment: shouldn't you install the library first before using them?

Comment: Do you really have `pip install PyPDF2` in your code? This would give you `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should open your file before using the pdf reader.

```
import PyPDF2
FILE_PATH = './files/executive_order.pdf'
with open(FILE_PATH, mode='rb') as f:
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(f)
    page = reader.getPage(0)
    print(page.extractText())
```

PS: you should download PyDF2 with PIP before importing it. Type this in the cmd 'py -m pip install PyPDF2' or 'pip install PyPDF2' and then remove that same line from your code.